# Remove section name from header in LaTeX

Tags: sectioning, header-footer, fancyhdr

I am trying to remove section names in headers. I am using `fancyhdr` package. When I try to specify new text in `\lhead{}`, text is just overlayed on section name. P.S. 3 hours of googling did not help.

Here is the section of code that I want to make work.

```
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\lhead{Student ID: 1123123/1}
\chead{University}
\rhead{}
\lfoot{}
\cfoot{}
\rfoot{Page \thepage\ of \pageref{LastPage}}
```

UPDATE: `\fancyhf{}` is not working - nothing changes.

*Edit by Speravir – Example taken from http://pastebin.com/W6V9GUCs

(link given by OP in [comment to Gonzalo’s answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/106944/remove-section-name-from-header-in-latex#comment233066_106948)):*

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{fullpage, graphicx, wrapfig, subcaption, setspace}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[font=small, labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage[protrusion=true, expansion=true]{microtype}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\newcommand{\HRule}[1]{\rule{\linewidth}{#1}}
\onehalfspacing

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% HEADER & FOOTER
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[L]{Student ID: 1123123/1}
\fancyhead[C]{University}
\fancyfoot[R]{Page \thepage\ of \pageref{LastPage}}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% TITLE PAGE
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}

\title{ \normalsize \textsc{SUBTITLE}
        \\ [2.0cm]
        \HRule{0.5pt} \\
        \LARGE \textbf{\uppercase{TITLE}}
        \HRule{2pt} \\ [0.5cm]
        \normalsize \today
}

\date{}

\author{\\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\
        SID:  \\ 
        University \\
        Department of Life Sciences
}

\maketitle

\pagebreak


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% BODY
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\section*{\textsc{SECTION}}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Put `\fancyhf{}` before `\lhead{Student ID: 1123123/1}`.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a "thank you" in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here to say "thank you" to users who helped you.](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about)

Comment: Please provide crucial information. Which document class are you using?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

To clear all predefined fields in the header and footer, use `\fancyhf{}` before assigning your headers and footers. Also, it's preferable to use the modern syntax `\fancyhead`, `\fancyfoot`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a5paper]{geometry}% just for the example
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum}% just to generate text for the example

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[L]{Student ID: 1123123/1}
\fancyhead[C]{University}
\fancyfoot[R]{Page \thepage\ of \pageref{LastPage}}

\begin{document}

\section{Test Section}
\lipsum[1-40]

\end{document}
```

[image]

After a MWE was provided, it was clear that the problem was the use of the `fullpage` package *without* the `headings` option; since headers/footers were used and the option was not passed, the header and the text area overlapped. The solution is then to load `fullpage` in the following manner

```
\usepackage[header]{fullpage}
```

By the way, since the `geometry` package is also used, I think there's some redundancy; you can use only one of those packages, depending on the desired page layout.

I also made some other changes to the document provided as MWE; particularly, I used the `sectsty` package to use small caps for the section titles (this was being made manually), and suppressed the incorrect use of several consecutive `\\` commands (producing underfull bad boxes).

I would also suggest not (ab)using the `\title` and `\author` commands to design a full titlepage (this could have undesired effects in bookmarks, for example), but to design a customized titlepage.

The code showing the changes mentioned:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage[myheadings]{fullpage}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{graphicx, wrapfig, subcaption, setspace}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[font=small, labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage[protrusion=true, expansion=true]{microtype}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{sectsty}

\newcommand{\HRule}[1]{\rule{\linewidth}{#1}}
\onehalfspacing

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% HEADER & FOOTER
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\setlength\headheight{12pt}
\fancyhead[L]{Student ID: 1123123/1}
\fancyhead[C]{University}
\fancyfoot[R]{Page \thepage\ of \pageref{LastPage}}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% TITLE PAGE
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\title{\normalsize \textsc{SUBTITLE}
                \\[2.0cm]
                \HRule{0.5pt} \\
                \LARGE \textbf{\MakeUppercase{TITLE}}
                \HRule{2pt} \\[0.5cm]
                \normalsize\today\vspace*{10\baselineskip}
}

\date{}

\author{
                SID:  \\
                University \\
                Department of Life Sciences}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Section title formatting
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\sectionfont{\scshape}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% BODY
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\newpage
\section*{Section}

\end{document}
```

Comment: How did you produce this image with two pages on the same file?

Comment: @Sigur I produce all my images by opening the generated PDF document in Okular; then I zoom them (in or out according to the case), and use the "Selection" tool to select the region I want to copy here.

Comment: But to see two pages I guess that the soon is to small. But your image looks like normal size!

Comment: @Sigur Ah, take into account that in this case I used `a5paper`; the zooming was `118.91%`.

Comment: That's the point! Now everything is clear. Thanks.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/W6V9GUCs - here is my .tex file. Your example works as a separate .tex, but not when I replicate it within my example. In the attached .tex section name is overlayed even if I use `\fancyhf{}`.

Comment: @doc please see my updated answer; what you were seeing is was not a header; was actually the title of your section. Don't load the `fullpage` package; to change the page layout, use the `geometry` package instead. I did some other changes to your document to prevent bad boxes; in some minutes I'll add some explanations.

Comment: @doc please see my updated answer; I added some other modifications (particularly to the section title formatting) and added the headings option to `fullpage` in case you decide to keep using it. I also added some explanations.