# LaTeX - Why does changing the font size of table of content affect header?

Tags: table-of-contents, fontsize, tocloft

Please consider the following code, I will then explain what I tried to achieve in it and how I failed:

```
\documentclass[a4,12pt] {article}

\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{indentfirst} 

\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand\cftsecfont{\large}
\renewcommand\cftsubsecfont{\large}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{} 
\fancyhead[L]{TITLE IN CAPITAL LETTERS}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}

\fancypagestyle{firstpage}
{
  \lhead{Running head: TITLE IN CAPITAL LETTERS}
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
}


\begin{document}

\thispagestyle{firstpage}

\vspace*{\fill}
\begingroup
\centering

Cover page stuff here

\endgroup
\vspace*{\fill}


\newpage
{\normalsize \tableofcontents}


\newpage
\section{Introduction}
Intro goes here

\section{Section 1}
Section 1 stuff here.

\section{\large{Section 2 (Which I am controlling the font size of)}}
Section 2 stuff here.

\section{Section 3}
Section 3 stuff here

\section{Summary}
The summary summarizes


\end{document}
```

1. To have a header on the first page that says "Running head: TITLE IN CAPITAL LETTERS" and have the rest of pages with the header "TITLE IN CAPITAL LETTERS," I used the following lines of the code: (10 to 20) and line 25.
   Courtesy of:

   - [Different header and footer on the title page (first page)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/351542/different-header-and-footer-on-the-title-page-first-page)
   - https://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=9622
   - [Remove section name from header in LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/106944/remove-section-name-from-header-in-latex/106948)
2. I noticed that when I chose a different font for section 2, this also affects the size in the table of content! The solution I found was to use the package `\usepackage{tocloft}` which allows you to choose the font size and style of everything in the TOC. [How to change font size in table of contents?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/64229/how-to-change-font-size-in-table-of-contents) So that's what lines 6 to 8 are for.

Now, it's all perfect, however, I noticed that, for some reason, the title "TITLE IN CAPITAL LETTERS" does NOT show up in the header of the page of the TOC!

Through testing, I now know it's because of the package `\usepackage{tocloft}`, because if I remove it, the header re-appears in the page of the TOC.

How can I solve this problem? Perhaps there is a better way of unifying the font size in the TOC without using the package `\usepackage{tocloft}`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can specify two versions of the section title, one for the actual title and one for display in the table of contents, by using the optional arguments as well, `\section[Title for TOC]{Title}`.

This means for your example that you don't need to add the `tocloft` package, but can just define the optional argument without the `\large` macro.

Full example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt] {article}

\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{indentfirst}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{} 
\fancyhead[L]{TITLE IN CAPITAL LETTERS}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}

\fancypagestyle{firstpage}
{
  \lhead{Running head: TITLE IN CAPITAL LETTERS}
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
}


\begin{document}

\thispagestyle{firstpage}

\vspace*{\fill}
\begingroup
\centering

Cover page stuff here

\endgroup
\vspace*{\fill}


\newpage
{\normalsize \tableofcontents}


\newpage
\section{Introduction}
Intro goes here

\section{Section 1}
Section 1 stuff here.

\section[Section 2]{\large{Section 2 (Which I am controlling the font size of)}}
Section 2 stuff here.

\section{Section 3}
Section 3 stuff here

\section{Summary}
The summary summarizes


\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: That's perfect! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `titles` option to `tocloft`.

```
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
```

and no need to change anything else in your MWE.